# Merging two possibly unequal lists with low amounts of structure

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, list, merge

I'm struggling with a quite difficult problem.
I want to calculate some kind of difference measure between two lists. One is verified correct data, the other has been generated by a program.
I want to test how accurate this program is, but in order to achieve this I need these two lists merged in some way.

Example data can be found below.

Expected output: A list of dictionaries, with each entry specifying if there were two matching entries. If they don't match, there should be an error type, specifying what is wrong.

The output list must be the length of the largest of the two lists, and each entry in this list should be one of:

- `{"matching": True}`
- `{"matching": False, "error_type": "deleted"}`
- `{"matching": False, "error_type": "inserted"}`
- `{"matching": False, "error_type": "updated"}`

I am working in Python 3, so if someone can provide Python code that would be amazing, but some pseudo-code that accurately describes this kind of algorithm is plenty of help!
If you find an easier way of representing the output data, that is also fine.

What I have so far isn't much, I really can't wrap my head around how to start this, but here's the small amount of code I have so far:

```
compare_data = [{} for i in range(max(len(correct_data), len(program_data)))]
for i in range(len(compare_data)):
    if len(program_data) <= i:
        compare_data[i]['matching'] = False
        compare_data[i]['error_type'] = 'deleted'
    elif len(correct_data) <= i:
        compare_data[i]['matching'] = False
        compare_data[i]['error_type'] = 'inserted'
    elif correct_data[i]['type'] != program_data[i]['type']:
        compare_data[i]['matching'] = False
        compare_data[i]['matching'] = 'updated'
    else:
        compare_data[i]['matching'] = True
    # I really don't have a clue what to do...
```

I was originally looking for some general kind of "Merge two unequal lists with similar structure" algorithm that could be applied to this, but I couldn't find an algorithm that achieves this.

Correct data:

```
[
    {"type": "a", "data": ["some", "random"]},
    {"type": "b", "data": ["data", "for", "people", "to"]},
    {"type": "b", "data": ["mess", "with", "on", "stack"]},
    {"type": "b", "data": ["over", "flow", "so", "they"]},
    {"type": "c", "data": ["can", "try", "and"]},
    {"type": "d", "data": ["help", "me"]}
]
```

The program can generate all kinds of erroneous data, here are a few examples:

- Missing entry:

  ```
  [
      {"type": "a", "data":["some", "random"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["data", "for", "people", "to"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["mess", "with", "on", "stack"]},
      {"type": "c", "data":["can", "try", "and"]},
      {"type": "d", "data":["help", "me"]}
  ]
  ```

  Expected output:

  ```
  [
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": False, "error_type": "delete"},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True},
  ]
  ```
- Swapped data:

  ```
  [
      {"type": "a", "data":["some", "random"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["mess", "for", "people", "stack"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["data", "with", "on", "to"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["over", "flow", "so", "they"]},
      {"type": "c", "data":["can", "try", "and"]},
      {"type": "d", "data":["help", "me"]}
  ]
  ```

  Expected output:

  ```
  [
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": False, "error_type": "updated"},
      {"matching": False, "error_type": "updated"},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True},
  ]
  ```
- Multiple missing entries with different type:

  ```
  [
      {"type": "b", "data":["data", "for", "people", "to"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["mess", "with", "on", "stack"]},
      {"type": "c", "data":["can", "try", "and"]},
      {"type": "d", "data":["help", "me"]}
  ]
  ```

  Expected output:

  ```
  [
      {"matching": False, "error_type": "deleted"},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": False, "error_type": "deleted"},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True},
  ]
  ```
- Multiple missing entries with same type:

  ```
  [
      {"type": "a", "data":["some", "random"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["mess", "with", "on", "stack"]},
      {"type": "c", "data":["can", "try", "and"]},
      {"type": "d", "data":["help", "me"]}
  ]
  ```

  Expected output:

  ```
  [
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": False, "error_type": "deleted"},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": False, "error_type": "deleted"},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True},
  ]
  ```
- Added entry (multiple added entries is possible too of course):

  ```
  [
      {"type": "a", "data":["some", "random"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["data", "for", "people", "to"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["oops", "with", "got", "mangled"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["mess", "these", "on", "stack"]},
      {"type": "b", "data":["over", "flow", "so", "they"]},
      {"type": "c", "data":["can", "try", "and"]},
      {"type": "d", "data":["help", "me"]}
  ]
  ```

  Expected output:

  ```
  [
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": False, "error_type": "updated"},
      {"matching": False, "error_type": "inserted"},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True},
      {"matching": True}
  ]
  ```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide some code?

Comment: Sounds a lot like [Needleman-Wunsch-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm)

Comment: Sorry @N.Ivanov Forgot about that, I had meant to include it.

Comment: What did you use in the end?

Comment: Still looking for a more viable solution. I tried out difflib, but it is still not really what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be diffing. Diffing is not so easy to get right.

Python has difflib with some of those diff algorithms built in. If you are OK with the results then you can use this kind of thing outlined below:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

correct = [
    {"type": "a", "data": ["some", "random"]},
    {"type": "b", "data": ["data", "for", "people", "to"]},
    {"type": "b", "data": ["mess", "with", "on", "stack"]},
    {"type": "b", "data": ["over", "flow", "so", "they"]},
    {"type": "c", "data": ["can", "try", "and"]},
    {"type": "d", "data": ["help", "me"]}
]

compares = [
    ('Missing Entry',
     [
        {"type": "a", "data":["some", "random"]},
        {"type": "b", "data":["data", "for", "people", "to"]},
        {"type": "b", "data":["mess", "with", "on", "stack"]},
        {"type": "c", "data":["can", "try", "and"]},
        {"type": "d", "data":["help", "me"]}
    ]),
    ('Swapped data',
     [
        {"type": "a", "data":["some", "random"]},
        {"type": "b", "data":["mess", "for", "people", "stack"]},
        {"type": "b", "data":["data", "with", "on", "to"]},
        {"type": "b", "data":["over", "flow", "so", "they"]},
        {"type": "c", "data":["can", "try", "and"]},
        {"type": "d", "data":["help", "me"]}
    ]),
    # ...
        ]

def data_as_textlines(data):
    'Turns a list of dataitems into a list of each items repr string'
    return [repr(item) for item in data]


correct_text = C = data_as_textlines(correct)
for (title, prog_data) in compares:
    print('\n' + title)
    print('=' * len(title))
    prog_text = P = data_as_textlines(prog_data)
    s = SequenceMatcher(None, correct_text, prog_text)
    for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
        print('{:7}   C[{}:{}] --> P[{}:{}] {!r:>8} --> {!r}'.format(
            tag, i1, i2, j1, j2, correct_text[i1:i2], prog_text[j1:j2]))
```

The output of which is:

```
Missing Entry
=============
equal     C[0:3] --> P[0:3] ["{'type': 'a', 'data': ['some', 'random']}", "{'type': 'b', 'data': ['data', 'for', 'people', 'to']}", "{'type': 'b', 'data': ['mess', 'with', 'on', 'stack']}"] --> ["{'type': 'a', 'data': ['some', 'random']}", "{'type': 'b', 'data': ['data', 'for', 'people', 'to']}", "{'type': 'b', 'data': ['mess', 'with', 'on', 'stack']}"]
delete    C[3:4] --> P[3:3] ["{'type': 'b', 'data': ['over', 'flow', 'so', 'they']}"] --> []
equal     C[4:6] --> P[3:5] ["{'type': 'c', 'data': ['can', 'try', 'and']}", "{'type': 'd', 'data': ['help', 'me']}"] --> ["{'type': 'c', 'data': ['can', 'try', 'and']}", "{'type': 'd', 'data': ['help', 'me']}"]

Swapped data
============
equal     C[0:1] --> P[0:1] ["{'type': 'a', 'data': ['some', 'random']}"] --> ["{'type': 'a', 'data': ['some', 'random']}"]
replace   C[1:3] --> P[1:3] ["{'type': 'b', 'data': ['data', 'for', 'people', 'to']}", "{'type': 'b', 'data': ['mess', 'with', 'on', 'stack']}"] --> ["{'type': 'b', 'data': ['mess', 'for', 'people', 'stack']}", "{'type': 'b', 'data': ['data', 'with', 'on', 'to']}"]
equal     C[3:6] --> P[3:6] ["{'type': 'b', 'data': ['over', 'flow', 'so', 'they']}", "{'type': 'c', 'data': ['can', 'try', 'and']}", "{'type': 'd', 'data': ['help', 'me']}"] --> ["{'type': 'b', 'data': ['over', 'flow', 'so', 'they']}", "{'type': 'c', 'data': ['can', 'try', 'and']}", "{'type': 'd', 'data': ['help', 'me']}"]
```

Check out the docs for difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes You'll find certain similarities in their example :-)